# Implementing NHibernate DetachedCriteria-like

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria

I would like to write something like DetachedCriteria but I don't want to use the ISession or Nhibernate at all...

All I need is the implementations for ICriterion and Expression.

after writing such Criteria -> I would like to generate an Xml Query or AD-Query or maybe even Query on collection (something like the Linq2Objects)

Do you have such sample? 
Someone wrote such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayende has an implementation for this.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/07/ComplexSearchingQueryingWithNHibernate.aspx

Comment: This is a great post but it is working with db not on objects.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you look in source code for NHibernate for implementation of ICriterion and Expression. It is after all an open source project.

Comment: I looked at the source code, the ICriterion and Expression are good for me the problem is the Usage of the ISession inside the ICriteria.